# Modulus of negative number

Tags: python, c

-14%3=?

C gives me -2 and python gives me 1. I have also tried many languages, all of them are having either giving 1or -2. Then I checked again, and found out that the compilers are giving -2 and the interpreters are giving 1. But JavaScript being an interpreter language, gives -2.   Why?

Comment: I don't see what it has to do with being a compiled or interpreted language.

Comment: Different languages, different rules. There’s logic behind each result; the logic is different, that’s all.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler op simply asks what the logic is. That's all

Comment: Just add 3 if you have a negative number. Technically this two numbers represents the same number under the module world

Comment: @jsheeran then why such similarity in answers?

Answer (score 2):

This is not a matter of compiling vs interpreted languages. Each language has its own rules.

For Python, you always get a result with the same sign as the *second* operator.

> The modulo operator always yields a result with the same sign as its second operand (or zero); the absolute value of the result is strictly smaller than the absolute value of the second operand

https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html